# Typescript: how to make return type only accept subtype of interface

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

Sorry about the title, I don't really know the name for this.

I'm writing a mapper function that take in a type and return a component in React and got confused with how to write return type for it.

Basically every component take in { data } which is or subtype of `IBlock`.

```js
// simulate React
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: P): string;
}
type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;

// actual code
export enum BlockType {
    'HEADER'='header',
    'HEADING'='heading',
    'GROUP'='group',
    'CARD'='card',
    'IMAGE'='image',
}

export interface IBlock {
    type: BlockType;
    id?: string;
    elements?: IBlock[];

    [key: string]: unknown;
}

export interface IHeader extends IBlock {
    type: BlockType.HEADER;
    title: string;
}

export interface IHeading extends IBlock {
    type: BlockType.HEADING;
    paragraph: string;
}

export interface IBlockComponentProps<T extends IBlock> {
    data: T,
    children?: string[]
}

const Placeholder: FC<IBlockComponentProps<IBlock>> = ({data}) => {
    return data.type;
};

const Header: FC<IBlockComponentProps<IHeader>> = ({data}) => {
    return data.title;
}

const Heading: FC<IBlockComponentProps<IHeading>> = ({data}) => {
    return data.paragraph;
}

function typeToComp(type: BlockType): FC<IBlockComponentProps<any>> {
    const map = {
        [BlockType.HEADER as string]: Header,
        [BlockType.HEADING as string]: Heading
    };
    return map[type] ?? Placeholder;
};
```

My question is: what should be put in instead of `any` here? I want to say: every type/interface that is subtype of `IBlock`

```
function typeToComp(type: BlockType): FC<IBlockComponentProps<any>>
```

If I put `IBlock` there it will complain for every component that take in its subtype, and I can't (or don't want to) put every subtype there.

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Having a general super-type of functions is not really type safe. Your functions are expecting to be passed sub-types of `IBlock`. Assigning them to something that resembles `FC<IBlockComponentProps<IBlock>>` would allow calling the components with something of type `IBlock` even if they are expecting a sub-type of `IBlock`.

You should consider rewriting the function, so that it returns the *correct* component type for a given type `T` and not just some *general* type.

```
function typeToComp<T extends BlockType>(type: T) {
    const map = {
        [BlockType.HEADER]: Header,
        [BlockType.HEADING]: Heading
    };
    return (map[type as keyof typeof map] ?? Placeholder) as (
      typeof map & { 
        [K in Exclude<BlockType, keyof typeof map>]: typeof Placeholder 
      }
    )[T]
};
```

We can construct an indexable type which computes the return type if indexed by `T`. If `T` is a key of `map`, the corresponding component type of `typeof map[T]` is returned. If not, we return `typeof Placeholder`.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGcEsFsFcBsCGAXApqASqxBjZBYAKEgDs0AnAM13QDFYS9IB7EgYWegAdXUyAeAAqgAvKADeAXwB8EoqAWgAFF3LMu4AFyhBASm3hk5UgHMA3EUlFkATy502Q0RJnP6jZC3aceJPsiFpC0IiEFBcZFhEeFAcZgATVCJUAA8ecmRQPlhoUAAheGYcAGsAFTt0cXlFAHIACQBRAEEAEQaMGpEagAtsRPIagBpqhXrmloBJADkAcU6evtMhkdAamYwAeQBVQXmTNVguZcJFVbYmjBb5nERyeOPTmomAWSaZhvmYRBNUY6sQwipdKZUgUag4dATApFYpyE6KWz2bTQkrlezBU6QeIAfgMRlMGMUqHgqGg-nAuNAUMKJQA2gBdYIrWnFVA2PHGEgmenaBjFEjMADuJGC-2SaWYGVAoNQVBoVLqfVlWRSaBI8XAVJRsKq8IUiNQyJpZQqADpGq12oT9ZBkCSOQTLERxcDpWRZeDIYrEPFTCq1Rqtca4acDUaYWjUObxtMZtbQFxbt9yIguN0HVzRc7ARKpTK5RCgzCONxeGRBGoNPxSv6+IHqTDZLrTvEUIhtKVhnrYt1IPB4uQ+JTDJyTAynQC4iRDDokBDusx+7LtLRHA2SiXfP4K+pwPx18VpLIxEpxK3kIhJLpRE2VoPIuQSKBz4hTQbRUzCFOZ97+iu19qm5lsgO5VhMv6ykezini+V43iGij3rAj7Pm2b62iSWaTqwP6LFy-77oBPjAaBe7gXhJhQSeZ5tnBIi3t2SEoS+pqJim+ypt0WFEJQDBMKwoAGqUzCbtWtbqpq2qRtIShhqApTXs2ijfpk0Cps4SmnAotJSWaFptBgPKgBB5Bdlpig6cakbRq0sZGb+pgrJI8ZMU+ShqVwtIGuEmqsjYzCUIJFQBaAHn0qA2LYrONALku5DXogmpKCs+rBYFHmgAAZBIoC0gA0m6oANCkODwLAiT8Lp9iDKAfkhQaIUedIRkNYFghzqgsX9KA-ynLotKlPSlifipoCDuACDIAAjM4QkiT4ShVVG+ntLooRgIoAB6UWjeNk1TQRB5AX45aVmRJlHtmu2oBN8DIAATLNFTCZui1WXpMazGthBhFtO04Zke13fdh1EaWJ0gWd+4OVyl3YdOgM3ZNADMT32C9C1Laa6zbHo62nNtsQA2NSN3cjoPGsd25QweR5AA)